# How to pass data and open an Activity from Widget?

Tags: android, widget, extra

I have a widget with only one textview,that changes every 24 hours.
What I want is when I click on widget top open an activity with text from textview.

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        TinyDB tinydb;
        Random r = new Random();
        int RandomNr;
        tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

            String[] list = tinydb.getListString(Constants.from_Quotes).toArray(new String[0]);
            RandomNr = r.nextInt(list.length - 1);
            String Quote = list[RandomNr];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("StartedFrom", Constants.from_Widget );
            tinydb.putString(Constants.from_Widget,Quote);
            tinydb.putBoolean("WidgedAdded",true);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.quote_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, Quote);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);

            // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
```

and There no extra passed..

on QuoteActivity.java I check like this:

```
 try {
           Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
           StartedFrom = bundle.getString("StartedFrom");
}catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I get null Exception.

I don't know where the problem is, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    TinyDB tinydb;
    Random r = new Random();
    int RandomNr;
    tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

        String[] list = tinydb.getListString(Constants.from_Quotes).toArray(new String[0]);
        RandomNr = r.nextInt(list.length - 1);
        String Quote = list[RandomNr];
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("StartedFrom", Quote);
        tinydb.putString(Constants.from_Widget,Quote);
        tinydb.putBoolean("WidgedAdded",true);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.quote_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, Quote);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

}


 And in QuoteActivity

 try {
       Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       String StartedFrom = bundle.getString("StartedFrom");
 }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: @Web.11 Can you please check or debug intent.putExtra("StartedFrom", Quote);  -> Quote contains a value or not.

Comment: It works now, I don't know what happened but just started working, Thank you.